# How i can setting the home directory for Pug in Gulp

Tags: gulp, frontend, pug-loader

I am trying to set home directory for Pug to Galp using this code:

```js
function renderPug() {
  return src('app/pug/pages/**/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug({
      pretty: true,
      basedir: __dirname,
    }))
    .pipe(dest('build'))
    .on('end', browserSync.reload);
}
```

But when doing the task, I get this error:

```js
    ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Boboshko/boboshko-me/app/pug/pages/photos/russia/moscow/2019/layout/templates/photos-inside.pug'
    at /Users/Boboshko/boboshko-me/app/pug/pages/photos/russia/moscow/2019/photos.pug line 1
Details:
    errno: -2
    syscall: open
    code: ENOENT
    path: /Users/Boboshko/boboshko-me/app/pug/pages/photos/russia/moscow/2019/layout/templates/photos-inside.pug
    domainEmitter: [object Object]
    domainThrown: false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide the code of photos.pug?

Comment: @kmgt sure https://pastebin.com/Ay956xik

Comment: Are you sure about `photos-inside.pug` is inside this folder `/Users/Boboshko/boboshko-me/app/pug/pages/photos/russia/moscow/2019/layout/templates/`?

Comment: No. `photos-inside.pug` is here `app/pug/layout/templates/`.

Comment: @kmgt thanks for the help! I found a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```js
const path = require('path');

function renderPug() {
  return src('app/pug/pages/**/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug({
      pretty: true,
      basedir: path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'pug'),
    }))
    .pipe(dest('./build'))
    .on('end', browserSync.reload);
}
```

And the path to the file must be specified relative to the root folder: `/layout/templates/photos-inside`.